# To use bracket or footnote in the academic writing?

Tags: writing, writing-style

For example,

> I'd like to introduce the saliency map (also referred as human attention map in [1] and [2]).

Or

> I'd like to introduce the saliency map1. 
>   1: Saliency map is also referred as human attention map in [1] and [2].

Or

> I'd like to introduce the saliency map. It is also referred as human attention map in [1] and [2].

Which style is better in academic writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To **draw the most attention** to *human attention map*, use the following, because the phrase appears in the main flow of text.

   > I'd like to introduce the saliency map. It is also referred as human attention map in [1] and [2].
2. To draw less attention, use the following, because the phrase appears inside parenthesises in the main flow of text.

   > I'd like to introduce the saliency map (also referred as human attention map in [1] and [2]).
3. To **draw the least attention** to *human attention map*, use the following, because the phrase appears outside the main flow of text.

   > I'd like to introduce the saliency map.1
   >
   > 1: Saliency map is also referred as human attention map in [1] and [2].

The style you should use depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: Note that I pushed the footnote symbol after the period (.). That usage is correct.